# Decompiler supporting Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, decompiler

I see that most of the Java decompilers support till Java 7.

Are there any decompilers which support Java 8 - especially Lambda expressions?

I want to run such a decompiler in my ubuntu machine.

Comment: JD doesn't seem to support Java 8 fully. Its online decompiler giving error! This can be found at http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: Trying to run JAD but getting following error: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't know why the earlier answer suggesting JD and JAD decompilers got disappeared from this thread...

Comment: Luyten decompiler providers good java 8 support and had GUI viewer https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon) and [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr) both support Java 8 language features, including lambda expessions and method references.

Comment: Excellent! Both of the decompilers support almost Java 8. Tested both of them. CFR seems to support more features or stable than Procyon. Especially streams feature in Java 8 got decompiled perfectly with CFR as against with Procyon.

Comment: Procyon console outputs with syntax highlight as against plain text output by CFR.

Comment: If I may ask, what worked better with CFR?  I am the author of Procyon and would appreciate feedback if you ran into less than optimal results.  Feel free to post to our issue tracker on BitBucket!

Comment: I have raised an issue regarding this in BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/issue/214/java-8-decompiled-class-is-not-matching Thanks @Mike Strobel for your answer.

Comment: I just 'java -jar cfr_0_115.jar Logout.class' and worked nicely.

Comment: Java Decompiler Gui for Procyon: https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten/releases

Comment: I don't understand why the topic is closed - Thanks Mike; CFR really works nice for me.

Comment: CFR has better support for JDK >= 8