# Vim and decompiling java class files

Tags: java, vim

I am originally a vim user and having tried IntelliJ as of late, 
I've been looking for plausible ways on VIM or perhaps a plugin to decompile Java class file codes such as the one offered by default on IntelliJ. Nearly every solutions I find seem to be outdated such as the JAD decompiler that is incompatible with anything that goes beyond JAVA 1.5 +.
Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307895/158037 as far I can tell both Procyon and CFR can be used from CLI

Comment: Vim is a _text editor_, so what you have in mind is out of its scope. Fortunately, Vim has excellent integration capabilities. Take a look at the built-in `:help netrw` plugin. If you have a tool that converts class files to source code, you can use like like netrw uses SSH to retrieve a remote file's contents.